# python 2.7 // operator

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point

I have code which only works when using the // operator and not the regular /. What is special about the // operator

```
return func1() // func2 #this works
return float(func2()) / float(func3()) #does not work
```

why?

Comment: What error do you get? `//` is integer division.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "does not work". Does it raise an exception? If so, please show the traceback, and provide sufficient code to be able toe reproduce. Does it give results different from what you'd expect? If so, please show the results you get, say what results you expected (and why).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `//` operator in Python is a "floor divide" operator.  Therefore, your two expressions are not equivalent.

For example:

```
>>> 3.5 // 2.0
1.0
>>> 3.5 / 2.0
1.75
```